# how to decrypt password in javascript

Tags: php, javascript

whenever a right username is given the password will be shown but the problem is if
the password is in decrypted format then when i am showing the password the encrypted password is showing...means if password is "pass" and its encrypted format is "1a1dc91c907325c69271ddf0c944bc72" then second time its pasting encrypted format into the password box..then password getting wrong..how can i solve it??means how to decrypt passwords in javascript..

//Index.php page starts here

```
  <form name="login" method="post" action="upload_file_enter.php">
   Username: <input type="text" id="name"name="username" onBlur="check()"><br>
   <?php if(!$_COOKIE['password']){?>
   Password: <input type="password" name="password"><br>
    <?php };?>
       <?php if(isset($_COOKIE['password'])){?>
   Password: <input type="password" id="pass" name="password" value=""><br>
    <?php };?>
   Remember Me: <input type="checkbox" name="rememberme" value="1"><br>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login!">
  </form>

<script type="text/javascript">
```

//this function checks whether the username is correct or not

```
function check()
{
  var username=getCookie("username"); alert(username);
  var name=document.getElementById("name").value;alert(name);
  if(username==name)
  {
    document.getElementById("pass").value=getCookie("password"); //here pasting the 
// enter code here`password in the password field if the username is correct 
  }
}
```

//getting the cookie value from document.cookie

```
function getCookie(c_name)
{
var c_value = document.cookie;
var c_start = c_value.indexOf(" " + c_name + "=");
if (c_start == -1)
  {
  c_start = c_value.indexOf(c_name + "=");
  }
if (c_start == -1)
  {
  c_value = null;
  }
else
  {
  c_start = c_value.indexOf("=", c_start) + 1;
  var c_end = c_value.indexOf(";", c_start);
  if (c_end == -1)
  {
c_end = c_value.length;
}
c_value = unescape(c_value.substring(c_start,c_end));
}
return c_value;
}
</script>
```

//Index.php page ends here

//upload_file_enter.php
//setting cookies here ..getting the value from index.php using $_POST and using here

```
<?php
/* These are our valid username and passwords */
$user = 'king1';
$pass = 'pass';

if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {

    if (($_POST['username'] == $user) && ($_POST['password'] == $pass)) {    

        if (isset($_POST['rememberme'])) {//echo"asda";exit;
            /* Set cookie to last 1 year */
            setcookie('username', $_POST['username'], time()+60*60*24*365, '/');
            setcookie('password', md5($_POST['password'])/*here encoded*/, time()+60*60*24*365, '/');

        } else {
            /* Cookie expires when browser closes */
            setcookie('username', $_POST['username'], false, '/');
            setcookie('password', md5($_POST['password'])/*here encoded*/, false, '/');
        }

        echo $p='showing some another page here';

    } else {
        echo 'Username/Password Invalid';
    }

} else {
    echo 'You must supply a username and password.';
}
?>
```

Comment: **Do not store passwords in plain text**.  Do not use MD5.

Comment: i am not showing password in text..u didn't understand if password is "pass" and its encrypted format is "1a1dc91c907325c69271ddf0c944bc72" then 1a1dc91c907325c69271ddf0c944bc72 is pasting as a password in the box normally not showing characters..but its not my password..my password is "pass"..it should paste "pass" in the box..not that

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: Please note that MD5 is not secure anymore. [There are much more secure hashing algorithms](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4789/most-secure-password-hash-algorithms), so when this is in your power, you should really change your hashing algorithm. It is also recommended to [store every password with a randomly-generated salt value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)) to avert rainbow table attacks.

Comment: Please don't use MD5, Use Bcrypt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you ensist on using MD5...

MD5 is supposedly `un-decryptable`, so the only way to check via JS would be to encrypt the input and check it against the cookie, but you will need to find a MD5 snipped for JS.

Try this http://phpjs.org/functions/md5/

I wont paste it cos its DAMN long ;)

e.g.

```
function md5(string){

    //make string to md5

}

function check(){
    var username=getCookie("username"); alert(username);
    var name=document.getElementById("name").value; alert(name);
    if(username==md5(name))
    {
        document.getElementById("pass").value=getCookie("password"); 
    }
}
```

**However** I would recommend a more secure algorithm for storing passwords which has a key/salt.

Comment: copy and paste the code in a php files and then run them..then you will perfectly understand wat i am trying to say

Comment: Problem is, you cant decrypt MD5... so you cant show the password in plain text once it has been encrypted. Click here [MD5 Wikipedia](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDEQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FMD5&ei=DI16UYacO4rltQaY64DACA&usg=AFQjCNGko1yjJrNR1YsAMRWdPKeO1Rkb_Q&bvm=bv.45645796,d.Yms)

Comment: thanks everyone i find a solution..i used base64_encode and used decode_base64() javascript function to decode the password...

Comment: Just to let you know, if anyone intercepted the data they can just see the username on the page and then do their own `base64_decode()` on your encrypted password to get it in plain text. Probably not the best way to go about it especially if its not over SSL either.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to decrypting password but there is an option we can compare the password with login password so no need of decrypting password using following code

```
Router.post('/signin', async (req, res) => {
    const { email, password } = req.body
    const userLogin = await Info.findOne({ email: email })
    const isMatching = await bycrpt.compare(password, userLogin.password)
     if (!userLogin.email || !isMatching) {
        res.json({ ok: "USER NOT SIGNED" })
        console.log("Invalid Credential !!")
    } else {
        res.json({ ok: "USER SIGNED" })
        console.log("wellcome user signed")
}
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.